# Disabling Javascript variables renaming in Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, assets

I'm trying to use tripleflap.js in my app. My view is calling the function:

```
<script type='text/javascript' charset='utf-8'>
    TwitterBird();
</script>
```

So, in application.js:

```
function TwitterBird() {
    var twitterAccount = 'ulmicru';
    var showTweet = false;
    var birdSprite='http://127.0.0.1/birdsprite.png';
    tripleflapInit();
}
```

Then I'm trying to run it, and Javascript debugger says me:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: birdSprite is not defined
```

In precompiled application.js in /public/assets/ I'm watching this:

```
function TwitterBird()
{var e="ulmicru",t=!1,n="http://127.0.0.1/birdsprite.png";tripleflapInit()}
```

It seems Rails precompiler had renamed variables, and tripleflap.js cannot find them.

Is it possible to disable variable renaming in assets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to move the variable definitions outside of the function, or just remove the `var` from in front of them, like this:

```
function TwitterBird() {
  twitterAccount = 'ulmicru';
  showTweet = false;
  birdSprite='http://127.0.0.1/birdsprite.png';
  tripleflapInit();
}
```

I googled the `tripleflapInit` script and took a look at it.  Basically it defines a bunch of configuration variables directly on the window and expects you to overwrite them; a pretty kludgy script all in all, but that's beside the point.

Because you're defining `birdSprite` inside a function with `var`, you're actually defining a new variable local to that function.  Even if it was not renamed by the minifier, the window-defined `tripleflapInit` would still not use it, but rather look to the variable defined on the window.

I'm not sure why you're getting the error that `birdSprite` is not defined, but it's possible that the compiler became confused and removed it, thinking it was unused.